# Trying to access exported function in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm trying to refactor some of my JS code and the way I handle exported functions within a Node JS environment. Originally, I'd have multiple functions exported from a JS file for instance *utils.js*:

```js
const function1 =  () => {
  // ...
}

// ...

exports.function1 = function1
exports.function2 = function2
exports.function3 = function3
```

and then imported into my entry JS file as:

```js
const anything = require('./utils')

// usage
anything.function1()
```

this would work, but my refactor isn't working... in that **it's not a function?**

```js
const function1 =  () => {
  // ...
}

// ...

module.exports = {
  function1,
  function2,
  function3
}
```

And used as...

```js
const anything = require('./utils')

// usage
anything.function1()
```

**Why isn't this now a function when it clearly hasn't changed?**

Comment: It should work I just ran an example and it worked, let me get back to it

Comment: I put the second version of posted files into two files, `utils.js` and `main.js`, ran `main` in node and it worked fine. Have I misunderstood the nature of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is this you are exporting an `object` but without `key-value` pair.

Just do it like this

```
module.exports = {
  function1: () => {
   return 'Jim';
  },

  function2: () => {
   return 'Jim';
  }
};
```

In this syntax you don't need to export explicitly anything.
Just read more about `module` exports [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Comment: The object notation `{ function1, function2, function3}` is using valid shorthand property names using [syntax introduced in ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).  That isn't the problem.